# Update valuenotifier using last string of a list

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter.

I have a list `led` which is initialize inside `BuildContext` which collects strings from other device thru bluetooth. I want it to update the `ValueNotifier` and change its value to the last string of the list.

The list is empty for few seconds.

```
    class _ChatPage extends State<ChatPage> {
      static final clientID = 0;
      BluetoothConnection? connection;
    
      ValueNotifier<String> switch = ValueNotifier("");
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final List<String> led = messages.map((_message) => _message.text).toList();

...
```

Please help me.

Comment: Please provide code to your problem

Comment: i dont see where is the problem but 
what i get is you trying to build the list inside the buildcontext but the list is empty for few second ,
you can check if the list is empty return CircularProgressIndecator otherwise you return the list 
this should fix the problem.
if this does not help please provide your code

Comment: My problem is the list is coming from another device thru bluetooth and i dont know how to make it update my valuelistener. I am only familiar on using textfield and button to update valuenotifier.

Comment: @Ali Nabel I cant figure out how to update `ValueNotifier` using a `String` from a list`... can you provide a code?

Comment: I still dont know how to update a `ValueNotifier` using the last `String ` from a `list`